# Concatenating Strings without printing to top of terminal

Tags: python, yaml

I have been trying to figure out why this prints to the top of the console instead of in it's group.

## Code:

```
from io import StringIO
import yaml
import sys

data = '''\
hLKJH3019
aaa
dDASJKLH3
CNBAhsa32
ddkLJASCNjdaskA
bbb
BNKASDL32
dDASJKLH3
CNBAhsa32
ccc
hLKJH3019
BNKASDL32
dDASJKLH3
ddd
ddkLJASCNjdaskA
'''

fh = StringIO(data)
data = {}  # start a new dictionary

for index, line in enumerate(fh):  # iterate by-line
    host = line.strip()  # do any needed validation here
    data[host] = {}  # start another dict to write to
    data[host]["nodename"] = line.strip()
    print(f"{host}.example.com")
    data[host]['username'] = 'rundeck'
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

### Actual output

```
hLKJH3019.example.com
aaa.example.com
dDASJKLH3.example.com
CNBAhsa32.example.com
ddkLJASCNjdaskA.example.com
bbb.example.com
BNKASDL32.example.com
dDASJKLH3.example.com
CNBAhsa32.example.com
ccc.example.com
hLKJH3019.example.com
BNKASDL32.example.com
dDASJKLH3.example.com
ddd.example.com
ddkLJASCNjdaskA.example.com
BNKASDL32:
  nodename: BNKASDL32
  username: rundeck
CNBAhsa32:
  nodename: CNBAhsa32
  username: rundeck
aaa:
  nodename: aaa
  username: rundeck
bbb:
  nodename: bbb
  username: rundeck
ccc:
  nodename: ccc
  username: rundeck
dDASJKLH3:
  nodename: dDASJKLH3
  username: rundeck
ddd:
  nodename: ddd
  username: rundeck
ddkLJASCNjdaskA:
  nodename: ddkLJASCNjdaskA
  username: rundeck
hLKJH3019:
  nodename: hLKJH3019
  username: rundeck
```

Expected output

```
(only for one result but this could be scaled to as many as are in the data.)
hLKJH3019:
  nodename: hLKJH3019
  hLKJH3019.example.com
  username: rundeck
```

The odd thing is that it is at the top of the console, when it seems like it should print in the group.
I am going to try storing it as a list and see if that might help, so far I have tried storing it as a variable also.

Comment: Why do you use `enumerate()` if you're not using `index`?

Comment: You're printing `{host}.example.com` during the loop, but you're not dumping the whole dictionary until the end. I don't think there's any way for you to mix your print statements into the YAML output.

Comment: Why don't you just add `{host}.example.com` as another field in the `data[host]` dictionary?

Comment: @Barmar how should I go about doing that?

Comment: `data[host]["domainname"] = f"{host}.example.com"`

Comment: The same way you added all the other fields to the dictionary.

Comment: That worked great! Can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks so much!!!